# can I use ".attr()" function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

".getAttribute" is used in java script inject coding.
in java script function ".attr()" is used.
So can I use ".attr" value is used in java script injection coding ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, could you provide a code example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 14):

No. `attr()` is a function of jQuery (and some other Javascript libraries). It's not a native function of Javascript.

In jQuery, [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) should be called on a jQuery object or collection. It cannot be called against DOM Elements. As you have correctly identified, if you don't want to use a library, you'll need to use [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

The following examples show how to get the same information using both jQuery and Javascript:

**Javascript:**

```
var src = document.getElementById('myImg').getAttribute('src');
```

**jQuery:**

```
var src = $('#myImg').attr('src');
```

It also worth noting the difference in jQuery between `attr()` and `prop()`, for example:

> **`attr( attribute )`** 
> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.
>
> **`prop( propertyName )`**
> Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched element.

You can read more about the differences here > [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cause it is **JQuery**

In pure **Javascript** use this (examples):

```
document.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href");


document.getElementById("My_img").getAttribute("width");
```